# How is Liferay HTML generated for the control panel?

Tags: html, liferay

In a custom portlet, we have configuration options under control panel-> configuration. However, there seems to be extraneous html inserted on the page - namely there are two places where 3 quotes are inserted. I've looked through the jsps and I think I understand how they generate the html on the page, but the issue does not seem to be there. Other than those jsps, what files does Liferay look at when generating HTML for a page?

I've looked through the jsps in html/projects/controlpanel

```
<div class="portlet-body">
" " "

....


<ul class="nav nav-tabs ">...</ul>
" " "
```

Comment: It's better if you paste the whole page html, use gist.github and share the link

Comment: are asking for the html-view of the configuration section in the control panel ? I think ist the config admin porllet .. the name ends with "web", if remembering correctly

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the HTML you highlighted, you are looking for the FreeMarker templates in the theme you are using.